# Are human beings naturally predisposed to believe in God?

Tags: psychology, religion, anthropology

My girlfriend sent me this [article from the Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/politics/8510711/Belief-in-God-is-part-of-human-nature-Oxford-study.html). This is an excerpt:

> Led by two academics at Oxford University, the £1.9 million study found that human thought processes were “rooted” to religious concepts.

[image]
<sup>Photo from the article</sup>

Not having *ever been religious* myself I am very skeptical of these claims. Please read the article for more details on the claim. Besides me thinking that it's an incorrect claim, I also don't think that it is actually possible to produce a reliable scientific study on religious belief and genetics—so the studies must be misquoted somehow or not scientifically based.

**Does this piece of news correspond to the findings of the studies?**
**Are the studies scientific or are they philosophical essays?**

Comment: Great question! May I point to [On the origins of pareidolia](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/on-the-origins-of-pareidolia), because there I've touched the subject a bit and linked to a talk by __Dylan Evans__ titled [Born to Believe](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zkJTBUnp7_8).

Comment: Good question. I'm not religious but I do think we're predisposed to believe these types of things. It strikes me as odd that countless cultures that had no communication with each other developed these very similar ideas that are, quite frankly, absurd. Can't wait to get some hard info on this one!

Comment: I wouldn't say "genetically predisposed;" but I do believe people are naturally inclined to look for the causes of things.  And when something doesn't have an immediately obvious cause, *"someone caused it"* seems like a reasonable enough answer.  Not too long ago, it was generally accepted that a god carries the sun around the earth; now very few people (that I know of) believe that a god causes either the sun or earth to rotate.  But it's still widely believed that a god created the universe, simply because we don't have a decent explanation yet.

Comment: @blu one thing is saying that some religious tendencies are a consequence of childish or uneducated thinking which has genetic or evolutionary origins, another is saying that thinking is naturally hardwired for religion. I have no problem with the first statement, but that is not what the article says. The article asserts the *second* is the outcome of a scientific study.

Comment: @Sklivvz Any other links/information on the studies ?

Comment: On the Atheists SE, I asked if there were any pre-modern societies that didn't have any religion or superstition, and the answer was "no". So the answer to your "headline question" would be "yes", regardless of whether this particular study was bogus or mis-represented by the media.

Comment: @And: and since when Atheists is a good source? ;-)

Comment: @Sklivvz: Because they'd be biased towards finding pre-modern societies that didn't have any religion/superstition.

Comment: @Andrew: or they could be biased towards proving that atheists are different from the masses.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm:  Are you assuming that Atheists are biased toward Atheism?  The non-militant Atheists I know aren't concerned with how popular religion was/is since the masses can be wrong (as has been demonstrated many times throughout history), and because they don't conduct their daily lives based on what everyone else appears to be doing.  Some of the world's greatest scientists courageously stood alone as they presented their theories, which were later proven to be true (e.g., "the Earth is shaped like a sphere"), despite tremendous pressures from their rulers and/or peers.

Comment: @Randolf Richardson: Can you name me one person persecuted for saying that the Earth is round? You may be thinking of people persecuted for saying the Earth isn't at the centre of the universe, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm:  Although it seems you may have missed my meaning somewhat, Aristotle certainly comes to mind as someone who was one of a growing number of people who disagreed with the idea that the earth was flat -- his other claims on a similar vein that the Earth was not created by some mythical character, etc., lead to the type of pressure I was referring to.

Comment: @If you've got sources, put them in http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/453/did-people-think-the-earth-was-flat

Comment: The photo is just noise and doesn't help in understanding what is being asked. It is also a waste of bandwith. It should be removed like greetings and the like.

Comment: @userunknown actually, we've already discussed this [here](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/844/about-the-use-of-images). One imeage, related to the subject, is acceptable.

Comment: @Sklivvz: I guess you have permission by the photographer?

Comment: @userunknown it's fair use (it's part of the article I am linking to)

Comment: The image illustrates what? Maybe I'm a bit dumb. Isn't it God and Adam? What has it to do with the question `religion & genetics`? It's a loose association to religion - nothing more. You have to know what the image shows beforehand, to even make the association with religion. Maybe it is fair use - I wouldn't think so.

Comment: *Olivera Petrovich*, from Oxford, conducted an interesting experiment. Olivera tested Japanese and British children from ages 4 to 7 by showing them photos of natural objects and man-made objects. When the children were then asked questions about the origins of natural objects like mountains and animals, regardless of cultural or religious background, the children predominantly chose “God” as the answer. They did not give an agnostic answer like “nobody knows” or an incorrect answer like “by people.” (Continued)

Comment: Petrovich called this result “absolutely extraordinary” because the Japanese Shinto religion doesn’t include this idea of God creating anything. So how do Japanese children get the idea that creation is in God’s hands when their religion and culture has no such teaching?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

## God? No.

> **Does this piece of news correspond to
>   the findings of the studies?**

[Belief in God is part of human nature](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/politics/8510711/Belief-in-God-is-part-of-human-nature-Oxford-study.html)  - The Telegraph
[Religious belief is human nature, huge new study claims](http://religion.blogs.cnn.com/2011/05/12/religious-belief-is-human-nature-huge-new-study-claims/?hpt=T2) - CNN

All correspond to the findings of a press release...

[Humans 'predisposed' to believe in gods and the afterlife](http://www.ox.ac.uk/media/news_stories/2011/110513.html) - University of Oxford

...and to any interviews given by the two academics from Oxford University that led the studies.

> **Are the studies scientific or are they
>   philosophical essays?**

Philosophical essays.

---

**[The Cognition, Religion, and Theology Project](http://www.ianramseycentre.org/)**

**Funding source: [John Templeton Foundation](http://www.templeton.org/)**

Grant Amount: $3,876,247
Start Date: October 2007

> Our Philosophy Grantmaking
>
> The division of labor and increasing
>   specialization in most fields mean
>   that some of the most interesting,
>   difficult, and profound questions do
>   not get addressed. We try to give
>   great minds the space and resources to
>   stretch their imaginations. We want to
>   work with contrarians, with
>   intellectual entrepreneurs. -
>   [source](http://www.templeton.org/what-we-fund/our-philosophy-grantmaking)

**Project Leader(s)**

- **[Justin L. Barrett](http://www.cam.ox.ac.uk/staff/dr-justin-barrett/)**, Senior Researcher
  [Institute for Cognitive and Evolutionary Anthropology](http://www.icea.ox.ac.uk/) [ICEA]
  [Institute of Social and Cultural Anthropology](http://www.isca.ox.ac.uk/) [ISCA], University of Oxford
- **[Roger Trigg](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/soc/philosophy/people/associates/trigg/)**, Senior Research Fellow
  [The Ian Ramsey Centre for Science and Religion](http://www.ianramseycentre.info/), University of Oxford

**Project goals.**

> The overarching goal of the project is
>   to support scientific research that
>   promises to yield new evidence
>   regarding how the structures of human
>   minds inform and constrain religious
>   expression. The project will conduct
>   research on the cognitive
>   underpinnings of religious concepts
>   and practices – for example, ideas
>   about gods and spirits, the afterlife,
>   spirit possession, prayer, ritual,
>   religious expertise, and connections
>   between religious thought and morality
>   and pro-social behavior. - [source](http://www.cam.ox.ac.uk/fileadmin/CAM/Anthropology_CRT_FAQs.pdf)

**The Science...**

**Cognitive Science of Religion (CSR)**

- First mentioned in [Towards a Cognitive Science of Religion](http://www.jstor.org/pss/3270329) by [E. Thomas Lawson](http://religion.ua.edu/aboutrelbiolawson.html), 2000.
- [International Association for the Cognitive Science of Religion](http://www.iacsr.com/Home.html) (IACSR) founded in 2006.

> ...CSR’s ability to bridge the gap
>   between strictly evolutionary or
>   biological treatments of religion and
>   strictly social approaches. Evidently,
>   however, the issues addressed by this
>   field are gaining momentum in the
>   public sphere in part because of the
>   anti-religious rhetoric that has come
>   to parasitize the field. We aim to
>   harness this momentum and attention to
>   maximize the scientific potential of
>   CSR, and to engage theological and
>   philosophical perspectives in a
>   potentially mutually productive,
>   instead of antagonistic, manner,
>   **pursuing truth wherever the evidence
>   leads**. - [Project website](http://www.cam.ox.ac.uk/research/cognition-religion-and-theology/archive-of-cognitive-science-of-religion-methods/more-on-csr/)

**Main findings of the Cognition, Religion and Theology Project**

1. Studies by [Emily Reed Burdett](http://www.icea.ox.ac.uk/about-us/staff/students/emily-burdett/)
   and [Justin Barrett](http://www.cam.ox.ac.uk/staff/dr-justin-barrett/)[<sub><sup>...press release text.</sup></sub>](http://www.ox.ac.uk/media/news_stories/2011/110513.html)

   - [The cognitive science of
     religion.](http://www.thepsychologist.org.uk/archive/archive_home.cfm/volumeID_24-editionID_199-ArticleID_1826-getfile_getPDF/thepsychologist%5Cpsy0411barrett2.pdf) Barrett, Burdett.
2. [Deborah Kelemen](http://www.bu.edu/psych/faculty/dkelemen/) from Boston
   University finds[<sub><sup>...press release text.</sup></sub>](http://www.ox.ac.uk/media/news_stories/2011/110513.html)

   - [The Human Function Compunction: Teleological explanation in adults.](http://www.bu.edu/childcognition/publications/KelemenRosset%282009%29.pdf) Kelemen, Rosset. 2009
   - [Are Children ‘Intuitive Theists’?](http://www.scipie.net/docs/2007/Kelemen_PS_2004.pdf) Kelemen, 2003.
3. Experiments involving
   adults[<sub><sup>...press release text.</sup></sub>](http://www.ox.ac.uk/media/news_stories/2011/110513.html)

   - [The cognitive psychology of belief in the supernatural.](http://www.jessebering.com/pdf/cognitive-psychology-of-belief-in-supernatural.pdf) Bering, 2006.
   - [Reasoning about dead agents reveals possible adaptive trends.](http://www.jessebering.com/pdf/reasoning-about-dead-agents.pdf) Bering, et al. 2005.
   - [The development of ‘afterlife’ beliefs in secularly and religiously schooled children.](http://www.jessebering.com/pdf/development-of-afterlife-beliefs.pdf) Bering, et al. 2005.

**The Cognition, Religion and Theology Project's interpretation of the main findings**
[*From the press release...*](http://www.ox.ac.uk/media/news_stories/2011/110513.html)

> The studies (both analytical and
>   empirical) conclude that humans are
>   predisposed to believe in gods and an
>   afterlife, and that both theology and
>   atheism are reasoned responses to what
>   is a basic impulse of the human mind.
>
> ‘This project does not set out to
>   prove god or gods exist. Just because
>   we find it easier to think in a
>   particular way does not mean that it
>   is true in fact. If we look at why
>   religious beliefs and practices
>   persist in societies across the world,
>   we conclude that individuals bound by
>   religious ties might be more likely to
>   cooperate as societies. Interestingly,
>   we found that religion is less likely
>   to thrive in populations living in
>   cities in developed nations where
>   there is already a strong social
>   support network.’
>   - Project Director Justin Barrett, Ph.D.
>
> ‘This project suggests that religion
>   is not just something for a peculiar
>   few to do on Sundays instead of
>   playing golf. We have gathered a body
>   of evidence that suggests that
>   religion is a common fact of human
>   nature across different societies.
>   This suggests that attempts to
>   suppress religion are likely to be
>   short-lived as human thought seems to
>   be rooted to religious concepts, such
>   as the existence of supernatural
>   agents or gods, and the possibility of
>   an afterlife or pre-life.’
>   - Project
>   Co-Director Professor Roger Trigg

---

## Reality

**The science does not support the conclusion.**

Given Dr. Barrett knows he is...

> ...an observant Christian who
>   believes in “an all-knowing,
>   all-powerful, perfectly good God who
>   brought the universe into being,” as
>   he wrote in an e-mail message. “I
>   believe that the purpose for people is
>   to love God and love each other.” -
>   [nytimes](http://www.nytimes.com/2007/03/04/magazine/04evolution.t.html?pagewanted=11&ei=5087&em&en=166dbd9e75680e73&ex=1173243600&adxnnlx=1305522983-QuW2p/rqr7fhZhVgOHHeqg)

He must also know this increases the chances his research could be skewed by
[**Confirmation bias**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias).

> These intriguing findings would
>   certainly be strengthened by
>   replications with additional stimuli
>   sets, alternative methods, and with
>   different cultural populations. As
>   they stand, they suggest one possible
>   cognitive reason for the culturally
>   widespread existence of religious
>   beliefs in deities that either order
>   or create the natural world: such
>   ideas resonate with an early
>   developing and persistent intuition
>   that the 
>   natural world looks
>   purposefully designed.
>   Positing a
>   designer (or designers) fits with our
>   intuitions. - [Barrett](http://www.thepsychologist.org.uk/archive/archive_home.cfm?volumeID=24&editionID=199&ArticleID=1826)

There is also the problem of
[**Biased interpretation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias#Biased_interpretation)

> We are moral realists. Gods, by virtue
>   of having access to the facts of any
>   matter, also know the moral facts of
>   the matter, and (perhaps not
>   surprisingly) tend to see things the
>   way we do. Theists, then, can glibly
>   accept moral realism. Not so for the
>   atheist. Atheists may have
>   approximately the same moral
>   intuitions and behave just as morally
>   as theists, but have some intellectual
>   work to do that the theist has managed
>   to avoid by relying on the authority
>   of the gods. Atheists have this extra
>   work to do in the moral domain, but
>   that does not mean that it cannot be
>   done. - [Barrett](http://files.meetup.com/918043/Barrett%202009.pdf)

And good old fashioned
[**Demonization**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonization)

> Refusing to accept that, in principle,
>   science could ever allow space for
>   non-material, even theistic,
>   explanations demands philosophical
>   argument, not an assertion of the
>   supremacy of science. The obscurantist
>   refusal to allow the theory of
>   Intelligent Design to be even
>   discussed in a scientific context can
>   only be the product of a
>   deeply-ingrained materialism, even
>   atheism.
>   - [The Religious Roots of Science](http://www.st-edmunds.cam.ac.uk/cis/trigg/lecture.html), Roger Trigg.

---

## The Bottom Line...

**The Essence of the Skeptical Position*.** <sub><sup>(edited for brevity)</sup></sub>

> 1. Extraordinary claims demand extraordinary evidence.
> 2. The burden of proof lies with the claimant.
> 3. The claim stands or falls on the quality  of the evidence the proponent
>      can provide.
> 4. To be taken seriously, claims must be testable, at least in principle.
> 5. Claims must be falsifiable.
> 6. The evidence must be public and accessible to all competent critics.
> 7. Science is a public activity based on **trust**.

**Failed on all counts.**

*[Distinguishing Science from Pseudoscience](http://www.sld.cu/galerias/pdf/sitios/revsalud/beyerstein_cience_vs_pseudoscience.pdf), [Beyerstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barry_Beyerstein)

---

Misc...

[Journal of Cognition and Culture](http://www.brill.nl/journal-cognition-and-culture), ED: E. Lawson and Pascal Boyer. Book editor: Justin L. Barrett.
[Cognitive science gaining ground in U.S. academic religion studies](http://blogs.reuters.com/faithworld/2009/08/07/cognitive-science-gaining-ground-in-us-academic-religion-studies/)

Comment: Wow. Great, great answer.

Comment: @billynomates Why refrain ?

Comment: It's an untrustworthy, bigoted rag. It makes up stories. There is even a website set up for people to view Daily Mail pages without giving them traffic: http://istyosty.com/

Comment: @billynomates Ahhh. I just linked them as another example of "Running a press release". But why give them traffic. I'll kill the link. Thanks.

Comment: -1 for providing a rich mine of confirmation bias for skeptical atheists but not actually addressing the question. Evolution could easily select for credulity if it has a positive value in survival.  And a natural belief in religion might exist despite it being *bad* in the current environment. And it is quite important to know whether the tendency is natural or not as strategies for dealing with a natural tendency of people will be different to dealing with a random aberration in individuals.

Comment: @matt_blac: I back you entirely and downvote as well. The scientists MAY suffer from confirmation bias but to immediatley dismiss their study because it agrees with their prior position which the answerer disagrees with is more toxic than engaging the paper on its merits.

Comment: @matt: -1 for the same reasons.

Comment: Does this answer the original question?  This answer just disputes a study he disagrees with, doesn't provide anything to support/debunk the claim  in the question.

Comment: It's not meant to address the claim- only the credibility of the evidence. It does that by saying the evidence is not credible. At no point is it asked whether or not the claim is correct.

Comment: @matt_black I wish I could -1 your comment.  This answer is not trying to confirm or deny whether religion is predisposition in humanity or not - it's addressing the specific claim of the article being cited **which is what a good Skeptics answer is supposed to do**.

Comment: @PointlessSpike Does the answer cite **any reason** why the evidence is not credible, aside for pointing out that Barrett is a Christian?

Comment: @gaazkam- Note that my comment is five years old. But from a cursory look, no, he doesn't cite specific disputes with the data or even specifics of the interpretation. All he says is that there's a potential conflict of interest. It's not a good answer, for that reason. I don't understand my previous comment. Unfortunately the links are dead. This answer needs to be reviewed.

Comment: This needs to be edited. Such statements like "God? No" and others are purely self-opinions.

Answer (score 25):

**EDIT TO ADD**: dancek (who gets a +1 from me) found the [actual study and the relevant information on the study](http://www.cam.ox.ac.uk/research/cognition-religion-and-theology/).  Given the list of authors, this seems to be a theology/philosophy study rather than hard science.  Furthermore, since this appears to have the hallmarks of a meta study, I must add in my thoughts on that.  The correlation factor (oft called Gamma) is pulled out of the air and pretty much reflects the bias of the people funding the 'study'.  They often rely on something called a Gaussian copula. Here's an article about a famous, Nobel Prize winning one.
http://www.wired.com/techbiz/it/magazine/17-03/wp_quant
different use, but similar method.  Basically the heart of the Wired article says that people will see what they want to see.  A sort of confirmation bias.

(*Original text follows*)  Sadly it's very difficult to answer your question directly since the Telegraph article does not link to the studies themselves.  Furthermore, it seems to be (at least the title question) a very philosophical question.  At this point in time, the only thing we can say for sure is that we don't know if humans are predisposed to believe in anything. Although I am familiar with some of the discussions based on personal research and discussions, so let's see if we can possibly get at the root of this.

First to address the actual questions:

> Does this piece of news correspond to the findings of the studies?
>
> Are the studies scientific or are they philosophical essays?

In looking at the claims of the article, I would *guess* that this is a meta study that would include elements of both.  Without a link to the actual papers and studies though, we are left very short on an actual answer.  ***Every single search on the internet led back to an article similar to the one in the Telegraph with no additional citations***.

Now let's see if we can ferret out some of the roots of this sort of thinking.  If you are familiar with Richard Dawkins's series "*Root of all Evil*", he posits the idea of religion seen as a virus in the sense of a meme. He begins by explaining how a child is genetically programmed to believe without questioning the word of authority figures, especially parents – the evolutionary imperative being that no child would survive by adopting a skeptical attitude towards everything their elders said. But this same imperative, he claims, leaves children open to "infection" by religion. (1)

I would personally posit that evolutionarily, we are predisposed to listen to authority figures.  An evolutionary benefit is that we would behave as a cohesive unit, and if this authority figure is older, or possesses some unique trait that allowed him/her to survive, that information would be a benefit.  [There are numerous studies showing how humans gravitate to authoritarian behaviour, such as the Milgram studies, or the Stanford prison experiments](http://www.sanctuaryweb.com/authoritarianism.php).  Religion has managed to hijack this particular evolutionary trait in such a way as to become pervasive throughout human society.  And if there is no specific religion, then another authority figure steps in to fill the void (such as a cult of personality or a political idea).

In searching for the evolutionary basis of religious thought, [I did find this New Scientist article](http://www.newscientist.com/article/dn13983-religion-is-a-product-of-evolution-software-suggests.html).  It has a great deal to say on the subject, and contains many useful links that could have been part of the meta study.  For instance, on sentence mentions

> Theories on the evolution of religion tend toward two camps. One argues that religion is a mental artefact, co-opted from brain functions that evolved for other tasks.  Another contends that religion benefited our ancestors. Rather than being a by-product of other brain functions, it is an adaptation in its own right. In this explanation, natural selection slowly purged human populations of the non-religious.

Another site seems to be dedicated to ferreting out how religion evolved in humans.  I haven't perused this site much, but http://evolution-of-religion.com/aims/ may give some data.  Be aware that this site is funded by the Templeton Foundation, but their aims seem to be interesting at least.  [This page gives an EXTENSIVE list of publications on the subject](http://evolution-of-religion.com/publications/).  I am not that familiar with all the authors, but I have a new reading list I think.

There is also the idea that [human brains are naturally tending towards purpose driven explanations for things](http://www.newscientist.com/article/dn16687) as opposed to understanding the full spectrum of how the world around us really works.  This is a hallmark of a young and immature mind, yet many adults exhibit this behaviour as well.

> called promiscuous teleology - in young children. Seven and eight-year olds agree with teleological statements such as "Rocks are jagged so animals can scratch themselves" and "Birds exist to make nice music". These mistakes diminish as kids take more science classes and learn causal explanations for natural events.
>
> A first round of experiments suggested that adults make more teleological mistakes when pressed for time than when not.

Finally, [Talk Origins has a page dedicated to the evolution of religion](http://www.talkorigins.org/indexcc/CA/CA610.html).

Sadly, searching for "the evolution of religious thought" turns up a lot of silly articles about evolution itself being a religion...  **Anyway, the links provided are a good start for further research since the media doesn't seem to want to tell us what studies were used in making their headline**...

---

(1) Lifted from the [Wikipedia description of his show](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Root_of_All_Evil?).

Comment: @Lagerbear, I only wish I could find the actual papers that the Telegraph article referenced.  That would provide a better answer to Sklivvz's actual question...  Of course, since when has the media actually been concerned with actually providing information instead of sensationalist headlines?

Comment: @Larian LeQuella - You can try emailing the author of the article  asking for the references if you are feeling proactive. I've noticed that people do that with some success when the newspapers don't print references. :)

Comment: @Larian, a fantastic collection of information for people new to the field. But you have not actually answered the question?  The answer to the specific question asked is: **"at this, stage we have utterly no clue"**.  For example, today, we certainly know beyond any reasonable scientific doubt how (say) mammals evolved. And we know what the moon's made of.  But we are, currently, utterly and completely clueless about this type of social-mental-consciousness question.  It's just barely "a field of study," far less a field where An Answer could be given to the question top of page.

Comment: (Just to continue for clarity..) I realise the questioner also had further questions about the particular study at hand, etc.  However in the large blue letters at the top there is a very straightforward question, "Are human beings naturally predisposed to believe in God?"  The actual specific answer to that question is, without a doubt, **"at this stage we are completely clueless, it is a brand-new field of study and thought"**.  It seems pretty important to spell out that straightforward, correct answer (to the straightforward question) clearly.

Comment: @Joe Blow, you are correct.  At least with `"at this, stage we have utterly no clue"`, although this isn't really a very new field of study/thought.  People have been thinking about this for ages (for instance, Pascal's "god shaped hole" quote).  We just don't have the tools to determine the answer yet.  My answer was mostly meant to address the other two questions at the end, but I will take your input and change it slightly.

Comment: @Kit Sunde thanks, I shall attempt to do that.  :)

Comment: Great.... Tim Ross doesn't provide his email address...

Comment: @Lari @Kit  One more thought -- By coincidence I happened to click on this question: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/598/do-violent-video-games-cause-violent-behavior Note that in the leading and most successful answer, the very first sentence (in bold!) is simply: **"We don't know."**  It's a case of "it's just that simple."  That's the only point I was making here.  Cheers

Comment: @Larian: Thanks for this. I'll have a lot of fun reading the rest of those links tomorrow. Cheers. :)

Comment: @Larian - The Oxford article is [here](http://www.ox.ac.uk/media/news_stories/2011/110513.html) and is says: `The findings are due to be published in two separate books`. A FAQ (PDF) for this project can be read [here](http://www.cam.ox.ac.uk/fileadmin/CAM/Anthropology_CRT_FAQs.pdf).

Comment: @Larian. You may want to review who the authors of the study are (I don't think it's published): [Roger Trigg](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/soc/philosophy/people/associates/trigg/), retired philosopher, associated with a [religious think-tank](http://www.theosthinktank.co.uk/mainnav/about-theos.aspx) and [Justin Barrett](http://www.icea.ox.ac.uk/about-us/staff/dr-justin-barrett/dr-justin-barrett-publications/), cognitive scientist, author of articles such as this [*slightly*](http://jaar.oxfordjournals.org/content/early/2011/03/29/jaarel.lfr008.abstract) biased article. Debunked 100%.

Comment: @Oliver_C thanks, I will have a go at that as soon as I get back from the hardware store.

Comment: @Sklivvz well, there we go!  Another hijack of evolutionary "listening to authority" hijacked by the religious of the world...  Oh well, I have some reading to do after the yard work.

Comment: @Skilvvz - Nice find!

Comment: @Larian _They often rely on something called a Gaussian copula. Here's an article about a famous, Nobel Prize winning one. http://www.wired.com/techbiz/it/magazine/17-03/wp_quant different use, but similar method._  Let me get this straight.   You criticize the authors' application of gamma, based on a popular article on the application of Gaussian copulas,  to a completely different field -- and how exactly are you sure its the same "gamma" they talk about.   What makes you think the mathematical issues that quantitative analysts and sociologists deal with are the same thing?

Comment: @Billare, sorry if I wasn't clear about the purpose of the added information.  It was meant to address the bolded parts of Sklivvz's question.  Note that I said "my thoughts" on the subject.  I do have a good background in mathematics, although not statistical as much as computational fluid dynamics (which could be argued to be equally nebulous in the days before easily accessible computers).  ;)  The reason for the Wired article is not about the mathematical formulae, but rather finding something that you just happen to be looking for in math.  That's all.  :)

Comment: @Larian Read up on the projects "Senior Research Fellow" Roger Trigg. He holds "There can be no Morality with out the Christian God" as an absolute. His ideas on "religious freedom" are chilling.

Answer (score 13):

[image: Cognition, Religion & Theology logo]

The referred research project is called [Cognition, Religion and Theology](http://www.ianramseycentre.org/), and **[summaries of the topics covered](http://www.cam.ox.ac.uk/research/cognition-religion-and-theology/publications/topics/)** are available (containing citations to actual publications, including empirical research).

The project has an [FAQ](http://www.ianramseycentre.info/seminars) that states the project goal as follows:

> The overarching goal of the project is
>   to support scientific research that
>   promises to yield new evidence
>   regarding **how the structures of human
>   minds inform and constrain religious
>   expression**. The project will conduct
>   research on the **cognitive
>   underpinnings of religious concepts
>   and practices** – for example, ideas
>   about gods and spirits, the afterlife,
>   spirit possession, prayer, ritual,
>   religious expertise, and connections
>   between religious thought and morality
>   and pro-social behaviour. Research is
>   not limited to any particular
>   religious belief or tradition. Indeed,
>   much scholarship in this area is
>   concerned to explain broad patterns of
>   recurrence and variation in religious
>   concepts and practices across diverse
>   cultural and ecological contexts, and
>   throughout history and pre-history.
>   The project forms part of a broader
>   field of interdisciplinary scholarship
>   on the cognitive foundations of
>   cultural expression more generally.

On the front page the research team is introduced:

> The research team consists of **experimental psychologist** Dr Justin Barrett (Primary Investigator, Centre for Anthropology and Mind), **philosopher** Prof Roger Trigg (Co-Investigator, Ian Ramsey Centre), and Dr Miguel Farais (**Theology**). Ms Ann Cowie is Programme Administrator.

*It seems to me like the research would lean towards philosophy and theology.* However, the project has included a huge amount of research on different topics by different teams, and I can't currently be bothered to really look deep into their research.

---

EDIT: A couple of quite good articles from New Scientist say that [humans find purpose even where there's none](http://www.newscientist.com/article/dn16687) and that [children naturally believe in supernatural things](http://www.templeton-cambridge.org/fellows/showarticle.php?article=8). These articles are be based on empirical research (though of course New Scientist is no peer-reviewed journal).

I've heard this kind of claims elsewhere, and I find quite believable that:

- People believe in purpose (even in some random things)
- Children can believe in God/gods without anyone telling them to

I guess one could simplify and combine *a prioris* like these, and come up with the claim *"human thought processes are rooted to religious concepts"*.

Comment: Templeton = *bad* source on this topic. They have a very clear selection bias in the results they use.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Ok, but they're not really the source. That's just a "reissue" from New Scientist that I linked to because the original was behind a paywall. I did note that New Scientist is no peer-reviewed journal, so feel free to question them, I don't mind.