# Is the Flat Earth Society for real?

Tags: society

There exists a website of the so-called "Flat Earth Society": http://www.theflatearthsociety.org/cms/

What I don't understand is whether this website is a contrived parody, or an earnest society. In the comments to [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/453/did-people-think-the-earth-was-flat), there is an argument whether the society is serious or not, with one side backing its claims with [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_flat_Earth_societies) and the other side still refuting.

*Does the society exist and do its members honestly believe its claims?*

Comment: This may be relevant: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/69358/will-flat-earth-society-membership-affect-my-graduate-school-application

I wouldn't be surprised if some actually believe but we can confirm that some people do it for the fun of crafting faulty but hard to disprove "theories".

Comment: @Murphy, exactly. And that's the reason for my question. To quote the top comment on the question you linked: "I suspect almost every member of the flat earth society joined for a practical joke or for trolling." (Is the commenter serious?)

Comment: Don't know why this is considered "opinion based" - the website and the society is either genuine or it isn't, regardless of our opinions...